# Можно ли как-то упростить пагинацию?

Tags: php

```
$num = 10;
$page = $_GET['page'];
$result00 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post');
$result00->execute();
$temp = $result00->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
$posts = $temp[0];
$total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
$total =  intval($total);
$page = intval($page);
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
if($page > $total) $page = $total;
$start = $page * $num - $num;
$result0 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE chek = "1" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.$start.', '.$num.'');
$result0->execute();
while ($news = $result0->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
// вывод страниц
}
```

При обновлении любой например из 100 страниц, формируется отдельный запрос для каждой, кажется. Можно ли упростить этот код чтобы создавалась меньшая нагрузка?

Comment: Если будете хранить число строк в таблице `post` в кэше, то от одного запроса можно избавиться.

Comment: нет, не буду) может можно как-то с подготовленными выражениями?

Comment: Подготовленные выражения подготавливают запрос. Mysql его все равно выполнит, ну может быть вытянет из своего кеша запросов. Так что кешировать единственная опция

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, судя по всему, не про рефакторинг ("упрощение"), а про оптимизацию.

> При обновлении любой например из 100 страниц, формируется отдельный запрос для каждой

Данное утверждение справедливо практически для любой страницы любого динамического сайта. Причем запросов на реальном сайте не один на страницу, а десятка полтора. Но почему-то беспокойство вызвала вызвала именно эта. Беспокойство совершенно беспочвенное.

Оптимизировать надо тот код, который работает медленно, а не тот, который просто "исполняется на каждой странице". От такого, взятого с потолка, "упрощения" будет один вред. К примеру, идеи про помощь подготовленных выражений. Которые сократить количество исполняемых запросов не помогут никак. То же самое касается и кэширования - запихнуть в кэш много ума не надо, а про инвалидацию никто никогда не думает.

Если же говорить именно об *упрощении*, то это вполне можно сделать, если пользоваться PDO так, как он для этого предназначен

```
$num = 10;
$page = $_GET['page'];
$posts = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post WHERE chek = '1'")->fetchColumn();
$total = ceil((($posts - 1) / $num) + 1);
if($page < 1) $page = 1;
if($page > $total) $page = $total;
$start = $page * $num - $num;
$pdo->setAttrubute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE chek = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
$stmt->execute($start, $num);
while ($news = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
// вывод страниц
}
```